# Where is the chat?

Tags: support, chat

I've been reading questions and answers on Stack Exchange for years, and recently decided to join a few sites. I went exploring and noticed that this site has a link to a chat room, but it doesn't have any chatting. It seems to be mostly notices of questions that have been posted. Does this site have a different chat room where people chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only because the users of this community barely use the chat room.

You did visit the right place, however. It's called [The Studio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38932/the-studio), and it's recently been filling up with notifications of new questions, because that's standard functioning of these chat rooms. But as long as no one raises a question or posts a comment, those notifications are basically the tumble weeds that emphasize the room's desolation :)